# Wordpress is_first_page() or similar?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to find something that checks to see if we are on the 1st page of the wordpress page page.

My current page looks like this:

FEATURED POST
six most recent blogs.

The problem is when I go to /page/2 I still get the featured post. I want it only to show up on the very front page.

Answer (score 0):

use `get_query_var()`:

```
if(get_query_var('page')==1 && is_home()){
  // you're on the first page of the blog
} else {
  // you're either not on the blog or not on the first page of the blog
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

is_home() is just what you're looking for... It returns TRUE if you're on the home page and FALSE if you're on any other page.

Comment: Not true. is_home() tells you if you're on the main blog view, and any page of it. Wes needs to know whether he's on page 1 of the main blog view. is_home would return true on page 2 as well, so is of little use to Wes.